# Static files versioning

Tags: playframework, versioning, playframework-1.x

I use Play framework version 1.2.5.3.

In templates tag @ is used for url convertions.

```
<link href="@{'/public/stylesheets/my.css'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

Converts to

```
<link href="/public/stylesheets/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

I want to set static link version parameter:

For exmpale, property in application.conf:

```
static.version=2
```

Template is the same:

```
<link href="@{'/public/stylesheets/my.css'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

And I want to generate:

```
<link href="/public/stylesheets/my.css?version=2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

or

```
<link href="/public/stylesheets/my.css?2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've defined the tag **static** as

```
/public/${_arg}?version=${play.configuration.getProperty('static.version', '1')}
```

Call

```
<link href="#{static 'stylesheets/my.css'/}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

gives me

```
<link href="/public/stylesheets/my.css?version=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

And I've defined tag **css**

```
<link href="#{static 'stylesheets/' + _arg + '.css' /}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

gives the same result by calling #{css 'my' /}

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking for the following format:

```
<link href="@{'/public/stylesheets/my.css'}?version=${play.configuration.getProperty('static.version', '1')}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

Though I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No. I want to specify version implicitly. Maybe override tag a or create new tag. Given url, it makes url with version (taken from properties).

Maybe it requires controller like this 

    public static void urlWithVersion(String url) {
        return url + "?version=" + play.configuration.getProperty('static.version', '1');
    }